# Cleaner way to include nulls/default values in arrays of anonymous types?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

So this code compiles:

```
var foo = new[]
    { 
        new { prop1 = 1, prop2 = "whatever" },
        default,
        new { prop1 = 2, prop2 = "something" },
    };
```

But the following doesn't:

```
var foo = new[]
    { 
        new { value = new { prop1 = 1, prop2 = "whatever" } },
        new { value = default },
        new { value = new { prop1 = 2, prop2 = "something" } },
    };
```

And so far the only way I can find to get it to do so is via:

```
T MakeDefaultOf<T>(T dummy) => default(T);
var foo = new[]
    { 
        new { value = new { prop1 = 1, prop2 = "whatever" } },
        new { value = MakeDefaultOf(new { prop1 = 0, prop2 = "" }) },
        new { value = new { prop1 = 2, prop2 = "something" } }
    };
```

But it would seem for both the first two examples the compiler has enough information to work out the implicit type of 'default' - so is there a reason it doesn't? Are there any ways of achieving what I want without an ancillary function or variable?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, you may get away with this:

```
var foo = new[]
{
    new { prop1 = 1, prop2 = "whatever" },
    default,
    new { prop1 = 2, prop2 = "something" },
}.Select(x => new { value = x } ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but this is for an automated code generation tool and I don't think that would be expected output, plus trying to work out when/how to use this method doesn't seem straightforward.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is more of a hack that needs to be specifically tailored. You may look into `Tuple` or named tuple for this kind usage, however, they have their own disadvantages. You can't make literal one-value tuples without Tuple.Create, and unless you use named tuple, you loses the property name (they defaults to Item1, [Item2...]), named ValueTuple is non-nullable, so casting would either requires a helper function or a verbose manual cast expression.

Answer (score 2):

> But it would seem for both the first two examples the compiler has
>   enough information to work out the implicit type of 'default' - so is
>   there a reason it doesn't?

The problem is not related to the array per se. It's the fact that the compiler simply doesn't allow you to initialize an anonymous type with a null/default value according to [Compiler Error CS0828](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0828):

> An anonymous type cannot be initialized with a null value or an unsafe
>   type, or a method group or anonymous function.

Let's forget about the array for a moment and consider the following code:

```
var bar = new { value = default };   // Or new { value = null }
```

Now, the compiler has no way of knowing the type of `value` and, therefore, can't infer the type of `bar`.

That is the cause of the problem at hand. All you did is that you added `bar` to an array of anonymous types. Yes, the compiler should be able to infer the type of the array element based on the other elements but now `bar`, as an element of the array, has a type that the compiler doesn't recognize, it wasn't able to make sure all the elements of the array are of the same type (because it's an implicitly typed array).

Comment: Well `MakeDefaultOf` is syntactic sugar, it's just a bit annoying I have to define my own function for it.  I.e., it seems there's no way of creating 'null' for a specific anonymous type without using an ancillary function (or variable).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any syntax sugar to initialize such default values.

The reason why second (`new {value = default}` ) initialization fails is due to

[C# arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/arrays#array-initializers)

> For a single-dimensional array, the array initializer must consist of a sequence of expressions that are assignment compatible with the element type of the array.

Compiler checks type of each individual element and then computes the best suitable base type. There is no second pass over objects to figure out if all can be made compatible with the likely resulting type (which had to be the first step to implement the behavior you expect).

As result the compiler tries to reason what `new {value = default}` is and there is not enough information to construct the type. Note that passing  `null` instead `default` would not help as it will not define particular type - the helper method you have need to be used to provide the exact type for `null` at this point. And the resulting type must be exactly the same as all other elements of array because anonymous types must match exactly to be assignment compatible - [C# anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types#remarks):

> Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and that cannot be cast to any type except object...
>
> ...If two or more anonymous object initializers in an assembly specify a sequence of properties that are in the same order and that have the same names and types, the compiler treats the objects as instances of the same type.